# Does wordpress vulnerabilities matter if it's installed on intranet?

Tags: wordpress, security

My company is considering installing wordpress as **intranet** blogging platform - nothing really complex, just clean installation without any plugins and layouts (we have a small team of web developers who will be handling layout customization). Wordpress will be installed on one of our servers that will not be exposed to the internet.

You can read a lot about vulnerabilities of the Wordpress platform, but do they really matter if the platform itself is available only within company's intranet? What would be the potential dangers?

Comment: This question belongs on a different Stack website.  It has nothing to do with programming.  Try https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Risk is limited quite a bit (as you won't be subject to the random drive-by attacks from bots scanning the entire public internet that anyone with a public server sees many times daily), but **not** non-existent.

A malicious employee, or a piece of malware designed to attack WordPress would still be possible.

You wouldn't want to neglect patching the WordPress install and its plugins/themes.

Answer (score 0):

If the hacker is also in the intranet yes. But I think in general no. For a good or a Bad just install  workfence.